# Can I append a tag/label to my Live/Outlook.com email address?

Tags: outlook.com

I have a email address from Outlook.com. My email is like `name@outlook.com`. Can I have emails like `name+newletters@outlook.com` just like we can do with Gmail email addresses? Does Outlook.com support it?

Comment: Have you tried sending yourselves such a mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

http://www.msoutlook.info/question/886

Try it out